# MySql: correct transaction isolation level to use for incrementing a number

Tags: mysql, transactions, increment, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Suppose there is a table in DB like this:

```
id                                       code
a8e09395-771c-4c6b-bb49-4921eeaf3927    2018-1
726b1390-b502-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459    2018-2
7a7ac7a6-b502-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459    2018-3
81758ea6-b502-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459    2019-1
```

Suppose there are **multiple** clients writing to this table.

For the "code" column, we want to ensure that it follows a **strict** "year-**nth** of this year" pattern.

What is the correct transaction isolation level that all the clients should be using?

----update----2018-09-11 11:31:24---------

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

SET @code = (SELECT CODE
             FROM hey
             WHERE id = 123);

UPDATE hey
SET code = @code + 1
WHERE id = 123;

COMMIT;
```

Did a quick test with the above transaction.

I started 2 consoles, then ran the above code, I ran them both to the line that reads the code column.

Then make one of them update the code column, it'll wait for lock.

Then I make the other one update the code column, it'll deadlock and rollback.

Now the first one's lock is resolved and it can commit.

So looks like this transaction isolation can prevent them from stepping on each other's toes, correct?

Comment: "For the "code" column, we want to ensure that it follows a strict "year-nth of this year" pattern." This can't be solved with a transaction isolation.. What you can do is make a trigger which counts and updates the code column and grant column privileges to every column except the code column.. Not sure if a REVOKE a column  privilege would overwrite a table privilege also not explained in the MySQL docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve this with locking.

It doesn't matter what transaction isolation level.

In one session:

```
mysql1> begin;
mysql1> select max(code) from mytable where code like '2018-%' for update;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
| max(code) |
+-----------+
| 2017-3    |
+-----------+
```

In a second session, try the same select for update. It pauses, waiting on the lock held by the first session's transaction.

```
mysql2> begin;
mysql2> select max(code) from mytable where code like '2018-%' for update;
(waits for lock)
```

In the first session, use the value the select returned to calculate the next value. Then insert the next row and commit.

```
mysql1> insert into mytable values (uuid(), '2018-4');
mysql1> commit;
```

The second session returns immediately after the commit in the first session. It correctly returns the new max code:

```
+-----------+
| max(code) |
+-----------+
| 2017-4    |
+-----------+
```

Now the second session has the lock, and it can insert the next row, without worrying that any other session sneaks in between the select and the insert.

Any transaction isolation will work if you use `FOR UPDATE` to lock the rows and ensure the transactions work serially.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not understand why "It doesn't matter what transaction isolation level.". Suppose two clients are trying to write to this table, they are both using a transaction with serializable level. That would ensure those two clients don't step on each other's toes, correct?

Comment: Try it, using the example steps I showed! You should run a MySQL instance in a local or sandbox environment for testing purposes.

Comment: Just did a quick test, please see the updated text above. (can't paste code into comments, format will be messed up :( )

Comment: Yes, SERIALIZABLE makes every SELECT into SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE. This is in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html But if you do the statements interleaved — do the SELECT in both windows, then try the UPDATE in both windows — you will get a deadlock. To avoid this, use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` as I showed.